# UK transit visa as an Indian citizen

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

Please note that myself Aniket Patki (Indian Citizen) having Italian one year valid Visa form 24-07-2016 to 07-08-2017 (Category D) with all Post office receipts and status of Italy Permesso di soggiorno. (Permesso di soggiorno already applied on 10th Oct 2016 and in the process to receive within DEC 2016). Attached for your reference

I am traveling to India on 2nd Dec 2016 and returning on 11th  Dec 2016.

**02 Dec 2016 Travel** 
Depart: Linate Arpt (LIN) Milan 6:50 PM to  Arrive: Heathrow (LHR) London Terminal 5 7:55 PM . 
Depart: Heathrow (LHR) London Terminal 5 9:00 PM to Arrive: Chhatrapati Shivaji (BOM) 
Mumbai Terminal 2 11:15 AM Transit time in London Heathrow is 1:05 hrs.  (Ticket Attached)

**11 Dec 2016 Travel** ( Ticket Attached)
Depart: Chhatrapati Shivaji (BOM) Mumbai Terminal 2 1:15 PM to Arrive: Heathrow (LHR) 
London Terminal 5 5:45 PM.
Depart: Heathrow (LHR) London Terminal 5 8:20 PM to Arrive: Malpensa Airport (MXP) Milan Terminal 1 11:20 PM.

I will not change Heathrow airport (Terminal-5) during my both journeys. Also my baggage will be transferred by British airline.

Moreover I checked as per exemptions part for Transit visa and I found out that I am exempted from transit visa requirement, as I am carrying EEA (Italy) valid D category visa.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. What is your question?

Comment: if  i required Transit visa in UK heathrow airport?? i am having Italian category D visa (working Visa)??

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are asking for a confirmation that an EEA Category D visa can be used in place of a UK transit visa.

> also I checked as per exemptions part for Transit visa i found i am
>   exempted from transit visa requirement. as i am carrying EEA (Italy)
>   valid D category visa.

Yes, this is the case.  When they made the new transit rules in 2014 they decided that a Category D visa mitigated the risk to the extent that a UK transit visa is overkill and hence not required in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you have an Italian D visa, you do **not** need a UK DATV. The same is true if holding an Italian residence permit. This is stated on the [GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no)